# show account chooser every time with GoogleSignInApi

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

I am using the new GoogleSignInApi that was introduced in play services 8.3. It remembers the last selected account and doesn't show account picker from 2nd time onwards. But I want it to let user choose account every time. Looks like the clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect() method of GoogleApiClient is not allowed to be used with googleSignInApi. Is there any way to achieve this without implementing a custom account chooser? I am on play services 8.3 and google services 1.5.0.

Comment: Try calling signOut? https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi#signOut(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)

Comment: AH! This worked. Thanks :D

Comment: I'm getting `GoogleApiClient is not connected` error. I tried calling `connect()` first but doesn't work. Any advice? Could you show an example how did you achive it? Thank you

Comment: Ok, I figured it and posted an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039247/logout-for-googleapiclient-in-android-application/43081102#43081102

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The account selection is cached, so you have to call [signOut](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi#signOut(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) first.

Comment: mGoogleSignInClient.signOut() worked for me, see (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInClient)

Comment: @szaske your answer is the correct one. Lol, the most simplest but the most correct!

Comment: but this wont work if want to reuse the token for switching account inside our app.

Answer (score 22):

Call signOut on GoogleApiClinet.

Where ever you are calling this code

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
```

Write this code before that.

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
```

So your new code will look line

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Now it will open popup again & again

Comment: short and sweet

Comment: Make sure to connect mGoogleApiClient before calling signOut. Otherwise you'll get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet`

Comment: thanks @Rahul  i was using Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient); at the time of logout only, but your last code calling Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient); before signin did trick for me

Comment: what if i dont want to signout and just want to clear cache

Answer (score 0):

Call revokeAccess on GoogleSignInClient

```
mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess();
Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

it will show account choose pop up  again and again,I hope this will work fine.