# Choose google account each time google sign-in api

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

I try to implement the Google sign-in API. It works pretty well, but I would like to let the user choose the account to sign in with each time.
For now, when I select an account, it's always this account which is chosen.

Thanks

Comment: try calling <code>signOut</code> before trying to sign the user in? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Actually, tje signOuy doesn't works in my case since the onConnect (i don'tt have the exact name), is not called in my particular case. It throws an exception. And also, with signOut, I can't deal with cached authentications, so since a user can login 100+ times a day, it is not good. I managed the problem by getting by myself the google accounts. I let the user chose which account to use and then I apply manually this mail. But is this a good way to do this ?

Comment: I think Steven is correct, you should try calling [`signOut`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi.html#signOut(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) so that you can choose a google account. According to [Steven](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35799186/5995040) in his previous answers, "account selection is cached." Also in that same [so question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783053/show-account-chooser-every-time-with-googlesigninapi?rq=1) there is a sample implementation you might want to check out.

Comment: The problem with signOut is that we can't deal with cached authentication. I know that manual selection is not a good way to do this, but the signOut method doesn't allow me to do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is no `force account selection` option. I logout user using `GoogleSignInClient.singOut()` before `GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent()` and seems that it is working as expected...

```
googleSignInClient.signOut();

Intent signInIntent = googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();

mainActivity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 12345);
```