# Google Plus Account Sign-In/Sign-Out not working properly

Tags: android, google-plus-signin

**Not able to select among multiple accounts(second time and above) while sign in via google**

I am using google plus sign in into my android app. Every thing is working fine. But when I try to login first time(after app installation) is gives me option to select among different google account(if i have more then 1 account login into my device) 
[image], But when i logout and login again it don't give me that selection option, **it automatically login with that account that was previously selected.**

**I am using this code for logout.**

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).build();
            GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .build();
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient);
```

I have also gone through [signOut](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/Account) documentation , What i understand from there is "Removes the default account set in Google Play services for your app" but it doesn't work. Is there any solution to do that ?

Anyone please help to find solution

Comment: Try usin this :- Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);

Comment: @Sachin Rao this is deprecated methods singOut() will do its work, see the link i have mentioned.

Comment: ok. Have you checked this : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect

Comment: See up in the code, i am already using same method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time, i found the answer for the problem, from the answer of [Rahul Sonone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37814954/7134908).
They only thing that did trick for me is calling signOut just before you try to sign in.

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me, might help for u.

While connecting use:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {

 GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                                                          .requestEmail()
                                                          .requestProfile()
                                                          .build();

                 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                                               .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                                                       Log.e("Error Google Conn", "" + connectionResult.toString());
                                                   }
                                               })
                                               .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                                               .addApi(Plus.API)
                                               .addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
```

While disconnecting:

```
 if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
 {            
  Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
  Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Did't see much difference in our code, but i will try and update